# Ошибка в обработке данных в R

Tags: r

Имеется анаконда/R

Работаю в Jupyter Notebook /R

Делаю:

```
data<-read.csv("Data_Projects.csv", sep=";",dec=".")

summary.data
```

Получаю:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): объект 'summary.data' не найден
>   Traceback:

Что это?

Comment: откатил последнюю правку, потому что она в корне меняет суть вопроса. новый вопрос лучше задать не методом правки текущего, а с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы. не забыв привести в вопросе всю необходимую информацию (см. [mcve])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю вы по привычке пытаетесь вызвать метод summary объекта data, но в R всё делается функциями, как таковых методов нет. Попробуйте `summary(data)`